Formula to grab values from another column and paste with dynamic offset
I have an Excel Sheet with values in column J starting in row 22. I also have a number in l35, this can change depending on values in other cells. I want to have a formula in column O, starting at cell O22 That does the following, it places 0 values in the first N rows where N is the value in L35, then pastes the values in column J starting from row 22. So if L35 is 5, Column O will have 5 rows with zeros followed by the values in column J. So basically, the value of L35 is the offset for the copying.
I am struggling to do this.
So far I have tried putting this in cell O22 and pasting it downwards
=IF(ROW()-ROW($O$22) < $L$35, 0, INDEX($J$22:$J$100, ROW()-ROW($O$22)-$L$35+1)) 

Any suggestions?

If you have Excel365, use VSTACK to stack a SEQUENCE with the values from J

=IF(ROW() - 21 <= $L$35, 0, INDEX($J$22:$J$1000, ROW() - $L$35 - 21))

A readable and easy to understand version, assuming you have Excel 365:
=LET(
    n, $L$35,
    values, INDEX($J$22:$J$1000, SEQUENCE(ROWS($J$22:$J$1000) - n, 1)),
    result, VSTACK(SEQUENCE(n, 1, 0, 0), values),
    TAKE(result, ROWS($J$22:$J$1000))
)

or if you want to stop after x rows:
=LET(
    n, $L$35,
    x, 50,
    stop, MIN(n,x),
    values, INDEX($J$22:$J$1000, SEQUENCE(ROWS($J$22:$J$1000) - stop, 1)),
    result, VSTACK(SEQUENCE(stop, 1, 0, 0), values),
    TAKE(result, ROWS($J$22:$J$1000))
)



@Michal, Hi, this works perfectly. Quick question, if  i wanted to limit the values to get from column J to let's say the first 50, and not the entire column what could i change?

@TendekaiMuchenje - please see the edited answer.

Stack Repeated Value and Column

The simplest way is probably stacking the sequence of the repeated zeros on top of the values as suggested by chris neilsen in the comments:
=VSTACK(SEQUENCE(L35,,0,0),J22:J41)


The following includes the additional requirement i.e. returning a specific number of rows.


Zeros (Integers)
=VSTACK(SEQUENCE(L35,,0,0),TAKE(J22:J41,L36))


Other Types (incl. Integers)
=VSTACK(EXPAND("A",L35,,"A"),TAKE(J22:J41,L36))

=VSTACK(IF(SEQUENCE(L35),"A"),TAKE(J22:J41,L36))

